# OpenLayers : Multiple layers popup issue

Tags: popup, openlayers, layer

I'm actually having a big issue that I cannot solve so far. Here is my problem. I actually have a map on which I'm displaying markers (WMSGetFeatureInfo) depending on some categories that I want to show or hide.

But here is the thing, I actually get those markers as a ***.map** file which is actually a PNG file containing all the markers.

When I'm clicking on a marker, I'm getting the position of the click and then add a popup. But the more layers I have display on the map, the more the popup is pointing far away from the related marker.

Here some code :

```
    var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
        category.label,
        "/mapserv?Map=" + category.url,
        {
            layers  : category.layer,
            format  : 'image/png',
            version : '1.3.0',
            srs     : 'ESPG:3163'
        },
        {
            isBaseLayer : false,
            singleTile  : true,
            visibility  : visibility,
        }
    );

    var info = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
        title          : 'get details by clicking',
        layers         : [ layer ],
        infoFormat     : "text/plain",
        queryVisible   : true,
        eventListeners : {
            getfeatureinfo : function( event ){
                document.body.style.cursor = 'auto';

                var getId = function( text ) {
                    result = context.settings.pattern.exec( text );
                    if( result == null ) return;
                    return result[1];
                }

                var id = getId( event.text );

                request = jQuery.ajax({
                    url     : "/cartoweb/FicheTheme",
                    type    : "get",
                    data    : "idGeoEad="+id,
                    success : function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
                        if (response == null || response['data'] == null) {
                            return;
                        }
                        context.generateAndShowPopup( event.xy, response['data']['metaData'] );
                    }
                });
            },
            beforegetfeatureinfo : function( event ){
                document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';
            },
            nogetfeatureinfo : function( event ){
                document.body.style.cursor = 'auto';
            }
        }
    });

    this.map.addControl( info );
    info.activate();


generateAndShowPopup : function( latlong, text ) {
    var lonlatfrompx = this.map.getLonLatFromViewPortPx( latlong );
    var anchor       = {
        'size'      : new OpenLayers.Size(0,0), 
        'offset'    : new OpenLayers.Pixel(-36, 6), 
        'keepInMap' : true
    };

    // Hide by default popup actually open
    if(this.popup !== undefined) {
        this.popup.hide();
    }

    // Create a new popup
    this.popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.Anchored(
        "chicken",
        lonlatfrompx,
        new OpenLayers.Size( 2000, 2000 ),
        '<div class="popupTail"></div><div class="popupContent">' + text + '</div>',
        anchor,
        false, 
        function(){}
    );

    // Popup settings
    this.popup.setBackgroundColor( 'transparent' );
    this.popup.panMapIfOutOfView         = true;
    this.popup.calculateRelativePosition = function () { return 'tr'; }

    // Add it on the map
    this.map.addPopup( this.popup );

    var that = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
        that.popup.updateSize();
    }, 50);

    this.map.setCenter( lonlatfrompx );
}
```

Not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but if someone already faced the same issue, that will be really helpful to know where I did something wrong.

Thanks a lot

**EDIT**
Ok so I've tried to reproject the latlong on the layer but it still not working. However, I'm making progress :

```
// Layer is the layer associated to each WMSGetFeatureInfo
// this.layer is the base layer used to display the map
lonlatfrompx.transform( layer.projection, this.layer.projection );
this.map.setCenter( lonlatfrompx );
```

**EDIT 1**
Ok so I'm making progress. I think I know where the problem comes from but I still don't see/know how I'm gonna solve it (yet).

When intanciating the `info` variable, I'm making an ajax call inside which will show a popup when click. The thing is that the more I add layer, the more this ajax request is trying to get information.

Let's say, I show on the map 5 differents layers (IT, design, startup, computer and desktop). Then when I'm clicking on a markers (WMSGetFeatureInfo), it actually try to make an ajax `request * [number of layers visible]` and then change at some point (sometimes), the position value.

In order to solve this, I will need to avoid this ajax request to be executed more than one time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When I first read your post, I misunderstand your "marker" with [OpenLayers.Marker](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Marker-js.html), I think you'd better still call your "marker" [WMSGetFeatureInfo](http://dev.openlayers.org/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/WMSGetFeatureInfo-js.html). It's easier for readers to follow it :)

Personally I think the problem you get is due to your map projection, your layer projection is "ESPG:3163" when you define the parameter "lonlatfrompx", you didn't reproject lon/lat (EPSG:4326) to "ESPG:3163". So it will be wrong lon/lat for the popup...

**Update**

By reading your "EDIT 1" I just notice that the way you write your "var info = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo" function is very strange, why do you need add a ajax call inside your WMSGetFeatureInfo? the usual way to do this is using "url" parameter to query the wms instead of using the ajax call. for example:

```
info = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
        url: 'http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms', 
        title: 'Identify features by clicking',
        queryVisible: true,
        layers: [layer],
        eventListeners: {
            getfeatureinfo: function(event) {
                // add popup here
                map.addPopup(new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
                    "chicken", 
                    map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy),
                    null,
                    event.text,
                    null,
                    true
                ));
            },
            beforegetfeatureinfo: function(event) {
            ......
            },
            nogetfeatureinfo: function(event) {
            ......
            }
            ......
        }
    });
```

**update 2**

First:

Yes, the WMSGetFeatureInfo will send multiple requests to WMS server if you include multiple source (layers). that's why your ajax called multiple times.

Do all layers on the same map position (mouse click point) have the same id (idGeoEad)? if they do, there is a quick and dirty way which is only providing the "layers" parameter one layer (instead of array of layers), then the ajax call will only trigger one time. Or just don't set the layer & url parameters, it will find the first eligible layer itself.

Second:

Even if that's the case, in my opinion it should not affect your popup position. Because "event.xy" and "lonlatfrompx" should always the same. So I think the popup is pointing far away from the related marker is still caused by wrong projection. 
So please double check your map projection, map display projection and all layers' projection. Also please check if all your layers' projection on your mapfile setting correct? Does all the layers use "EPSG:3163" ?
In your code above I notice that a typo "srs : 'ESPG:3163'", it should be EPSG:3163.

If you use fire-bug or google developer tool, please debug or console.log to see if "event.xy" and "lonlatfrompx" will get the correct position every time.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. That's interesting. However, since I'm newbie to Openlayer, what can I do then? I edited my post after try another things but still no success :(. Thanks

Comment: Hi, thanks for the update. I'm using ajax because the url is different from the WMS server `/cartoweb/FicheTheme?idGeoEad=`. The actual system is not based on the server to retreive data so I need to query a specific URL containing an ID in order to get back the information related to a marker. A weird behavior I noticed is that if there is for example 3 layers on the map, the `eventListeners : getfeatureinfo` is executed 3 times, and sometimes return mulitple values. At that moment is seems to break. I've try to use `drillDown` but still not working :(. Thoughts?

Comment: Hi El - Key, I find that it's hard to format my answer on comment here, so I will keep updating on my post above :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your update. About the typo, yeah I found out and changed it but forgot to update it as well here. I checked the projection for the map, baseLayer and all others layers and they all use `EPSG:3163`. 
Regarding your first point, when I'm changing this `layers : [ layer ]` to `layers : layer` the popup does not show anymore. 
But I realized something : this bug does not happen when I put a marker in the center of the map (map drag) and I click on it. Then the more a marker will be far away from the center, the more the popup will be far away from it as well.